# why my edittext cannot start with "0" android studio?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to ask you in android studio my EditText for Phone number can't start with 0 it automatically remove "0" and start with the other numbers.

For Example:
  when i type: 123123 it works with no problems, but
  when i type: 08512359 automatically remove "0" and go forward with the other numbers(8512359).

My question is how to make it works with 0 ? Is there any options in the properties of the EditText or not ?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
        android:layout_weight="7" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Phone number"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="5" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/numberEditText"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:editable="false"
        android:maxLength="11"
        android:phoneNumber="false" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="City"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cityEditText"
        android:layout_weight="7" />
</LinearLayout>

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:id="@+id/sexRadioGroup">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Sex:"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="M"
        android:id="@+id/maleRadioButton"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:checked="false" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="F"
        android:id="@+id/femaleRadioButton"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:checked="false" />

</RadioGroup>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:id="@+id/okButton"
        android:layout_weight="5" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_weight="5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: **Wild guess**: you are converting the text to a `number`.

Comment: so how i must convert it ?

Comment: Please show your XML and your relevant code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/x9aqk9LM

Comment: have you used to input type as number in XML.

Comment: my input type is: phone

Comment: try to remove the attribute: android:phoneNumber="false"

Comment: i remove it but it doesnt work again

Answer (score 0):

For format phonenumbers, use the libphonenumber...

https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Easy, lightweight, faster..

Answer (score 0):

```
android:ems="10"
```

**Replace with**

```
android:ems="11"
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the input in form of `String` instead of `int`, for example:

```
String phoneNumber = editText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: can you post your java code where you are taking the value from edit text and storing it on a variable?